# While I have six eyes, I don't need an optician

Tags: riddle, word

I thought I might try writing a riddle.  Maybe this is too simple for some of the adept riddle solvers, but oh well.  Here it is:

```
While I have six eyes, I don't need an optician.
There's just one factor to my primary condition.
Emerge from the inn, then head off to the right.
End with tea, where you can trust your eyesight.
```

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are:

> **Indivisibility**

*While I have six eyes, I don't need an optician.*

> Indivisibility contains 6 of the letter **i**, but doesn't have anything to do with optometry

*There's just one factor to my primary condition.*

> Something with 1 factor is indivisible by anything else

*Emerge from the inn, then head off to the right.*

> The word indivisibility starts with **in** (sounds like "inn"), with "head off" to the right - this could either mean **div** in the sense of separating from the inn, or in the sense of `<div/>` having similarity to `<head/>` as a valid HTML tag

*End with tea, where you can trust your eyesight.*

> The word indivisibility ends with **visibility**, which itself ends with **ty** (sounds like "tea").

Comment: I’ll tick this one because the explanation is slightly closer to what I was thinking.  Well done (: I’m fairly happy with how it turned out.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Can you explain the "Emerge from the inn, then head off to the right" clue?

Comment: It's not that exciting, I just meant rot13("va" = "vaa" vf ba gur yrsg bs gur jbeq, lbh urnq gb gur evtug naq lbh ernq "gl" = "grn" juvpu vf vafvqr "ivfvovyvgl").  I mostly just wanted the strings to line up.  (:

Answer (score 7):

You are:

> INDIVISIBILITY

While I have six eyes, I don't need an optician.

> 6 I's

There's just one factor to my primary condition.

> Prime numbers are indivisible.  (one factor, other than one)

Emerge from the inn, then head off to the right.
End with tea, where you can trust your eyesight.

> Wordplay here -- IN + ??? + TY (tea) Not sure if the DIVISIBILI is clued.  But, since it's not a cryptic, full cluing ins't required.

Comment: Nooooo, preempted by 1 minute :( +1 anyways :)

Comment: Avi needs the rep when it comes to awarding checkmarks.